# _COMPlusExceptionCode -532462766 while getting data async by stored procedure

Tags: wpf, stored-procedures, asynchronous

In my WPF application, when the user select a row in datagrid, I invoke the method in viewModel that should get some data asynchronously:

```
private async void LoadAdditionalInfoForItem(int itemId, int? supplierId)
    {            
        try
        {
            var result = await unitOfWork.ItemRepository.GetReplacementsByOEMAsync(langId, itemId);

            // Got an error here with no details, just _COMPlusExceptionCode -532462766
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }
```

In ItemRepository class:

```
public Task<ObservableCollection<GetItemListProcedureResult>> GetReplacementsByOEMAsync(int langId, int itemId)
        {
            return _context.GetReplacementsByOEMProcedure(langId, itemId).ToObservableCollectionAsync();
        }
```

And extension method:

```
public static Task<ObservableCollection<T>> ToObservableCollectionAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> col)
        {
            return Task<ObservableCollection<T>>.Factory.StartNew(() => new ObservableCollection<T>(col));
        }
```

I get another data async the same way (with another SP) in the same method and it's OK. I checked stored procedure GetReplacementsByOEMProcedure stand-alone and it returns right data.

So, maybe someone faced the same problem? I don't have a clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that two SP return the same class of returned collection. As I changed the first SP, I didn't change the second one and because of this in the second SP (GetReplacementsByOEMProcedure) column name was not mapped to the field of returned class.